# Uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove the following problem:

If $P_n$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions which converges on the unit disc $D$ and that has a subsequence which converges uniformly on every compact set of  $D$ then $P_n$ converges uniformly on every compact set of $D$.

Comment: the first "convergence" means pointwise convergence?